# Mongoose not saving data for api/mlab

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a search api that you can search using the imgur api and it'll return json data of the images, but will also record your latest search in the "/latest" url. The only problem is it returns an empty array which leads me to believe my mlab database isn't saving anything despite having a save method.

Whole file: https://github.com/jeffm64/image-search-abstraction-layer

the code that may be not allowing it: index.js

```
        router.get("/latest", function (req, res) {
          History.find({}, 'term when -_id').sort('-when').limit(10).then(function (results) {
            res.json(results);
          });
        });

        router.get("/search/:q", function (req, res) {
          imgur.getImage(req.params.q, req.query.offset).then(function (ans) {
            new History({ term: req.params.q }).save();
            res.json(ans);
          });
        });
```

history.js

```
var historySchema = new mongoose.Schema({  term: String,  when: { type: Date, default: Date.now } });

var History = mongoose.model("History", historySchema);
```

Comment: Try `req.query.q` instead of `req.params.q`. What the api call looks like?

Comment: Just tried it but didn't seem to change anything. I'm still pretty new to node when you say api call do you mean what function uses it, or path location to use the searches, or the imgur file of the code that allows it to work with imgur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the answer to this is super noob level. It wouldn't connect to the database because you made the user login for mlabs database read me only on accident. I guess I will leave this in case some other poor soul spends 15+ hours troubleshooting code that's probably fine!